# How to simplify units with different scales in SymPy

Tags: sympy

In `sympy.physics.units` identical units automatically simplify when they are used in equations. However, when units are different scales of the same dimension, they are not automatically simplified. For example:

```py
from sympy.physics.units import *

(5000 * gram) / (2 * gram)
# 2500

(5 * kilogram) / (2 * gram)
# (5 * kilogram) / (2 * gram)

5 * gram + 1 * kilogram
# 5*gram + kilogram

5 * gram + 1000 * gram
# 1005*gram

1000*liter/(5000*liter)
# 1/5

1000*liter/(5*meter**3)
# 200*liter/meter**3
```

Is there an easy way to force unit simplification, at least in cases where the units are different scales of the same dimension?

I am looking for the same effect as using `.subs()` on all the units, just automated to use the information already contained in the expression, equivalent to

```
((5 * kilogram) / (2 * gram)).subs({gram: gram, kilogram: 1000 * gram, ...})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue of scale can be solved by [`print_unit_base`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/units/unitsystem.html#sympy.physics.units.unitsystem.UnitSystem.print_unit_base) method of the unit system. For example,

```
from sympy.physics.units.systems import MKS
expr = (5 * kilogram) / (2 * gram)
new_expr = expr.xreplace({q: MKS.print_unit_base(q) for q in expr.atoms(Quantity)})
```

Now `new_expr` is 2500.

A simpler function to use is [`convert_to(expr, kilogram)`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/units/quantities.html#sympy.physics.units.util.convert_to) (which also returns 2500) but this depends on knowing that units of mass are an issue. `print_unit_base` uniformizes all units of the given unit system.

With `liter`, since it's not really a prefixed-meter-cubed, we need `convert_to`:

```
expr2 = 1000*liter/(5*meter**3)
convert_to(expr2, meter)     #  1/5
```